# Publish Build Artifacts: Invalid Parameter: "/MT:8"

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, robocopy

I have a problem with `Publish Build Artifacts` task in build definition. When it was added to the definition it had `Paraller Copy` option set to `8`. After change to `4` it broke itself even when the change is reverted. Now it works only when `Paraller Copy` option is disabled. Here is the log file:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: Publish Artifact to
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish Build Artifacts
Description  : Publish Build artifacts to the server or a file share
Version      : 1.120.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708390)
==============================================================================
robocopy.exe /E /COPY:DA /NP /R:3 /MT:8 "C:\BuildAgent-Publish\_work\1\s\Kdp" "C:\InstallationDataTemp" *
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows     ::     Version XP010
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Started : Tue Oct 15 14:22:25 2019
   Source - 
     Dest - 
    Files : 
  Options : /S /E /COPY:DAT /NP /R:3 /W:30 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #5 : "/MT:8"
       Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR
             source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.
    For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /? or read Robocopy.Doc.
NOTE: Read "True Replication" in Robocopy.Doc prior to first use of /MIR !
****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
robocopy exit code '16'
Publish build artifacts failed with error: powershell.exe failed with return code: 1
******************************************************************************
Async Command Start: Associate Artifact
******************************************************************************
Associated artifact 22 with build 227
******************************************************************************
Async Command End: Associate Artifact
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Publish Artifact to
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: According to the blog: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2008/06/16/robocopy-exit-codes/ and exit code of 16 means this:

*Robocopy did not copy any files.  Check the command line parameters and verify that Robocopy has enough rights to write to the destination folder.*

Does your agent have rights to write at the destination?

Comment: Yes it does have the rights.

Comment: Like riQQ mentioned, XP010 is from the 2003 resource kit.  Is this a 2003 or earlier server server? You might have to either install a newer version of robocopy or change you build to call the regular copy command.  I'm curious though, you said it worked before, did you change anything else in your build definition?  After 2003, robocopy is included with windows so you can't get a newer version.

Comment: I'm using `Windows Server 2016 Standard`. Thank you, after uninstalling `Windows Resource Kit 2003` it now uses the version that is included in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `robocopy` is included in Windows after 2003 the only need was to uninstall `Windows Resource Kit 2003` to make task use the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

The build is using robocopy Version XP010 which doesn't support this parameter.

Maybe you have changed something else that causes the build to run on another agent.

Comment: Is this TFS or Azure DevOps?

Comment: This is TFS, not Azure DevOps.

Comment: Do you have control over the build agents? Which Windows version is running on the build agents?

Comment: I'm using `Windows Server 2016 Standard`. Issue have been solved after uninstalling Windows Resource Kit 2003. Now it uses the version that is included in Windows.